# Google Actions/Home/Assistant - Custom App Name not recognized. Mistaken for another word

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

been trying to figure out how to resolve this.

I have an app via api.ai to Google Assistant for Google Home and if I "type" my app into google assistant in test mode, it works. For example "Hey Google, let me talk to Simonee". Google Assistant replies with "Sure, here is Sinomee and then the app kicks in".

However, if I speak it, no matter how I try it, over the mic, Google Assistant thinks I'm saying "cinnamon".  Is there any way to register the name of the app on Google home? or tell is the pronunciation so it knows to kick off your app? So that the name of the app overrides a similar word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're still testing, there isn't much that you can do. Adding a shortcut through the Google Home app might help.

However, when you submit your app for review, one of the things you need to do is specify the invocation name, which can be different than the name of the app itself. This is to deal with pronunciation issues, and is why they suggest you record the invocation name, rather than typing it in. For very complicated pronunciations, you may wish to also specify in the notes how it is pronounced and why - this will help them shape the recognizer to capture your name correctly.

[image]