# Android assistant - MediaBrowserService - Voice command - "Play x on appName"

Tags: android, assistant, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowserservice

The voice commande Play [song] on [my appName] command not working, the "appName" is not being recognised by google assistante.

I followed the instruction form https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant and the demo app form https://github.com/android/uamp

My AndroidManifest:

```
    <application
android:name=".XApplication"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" // app_name = appX 101.1
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

     <activity
        android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppFullScreenTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
...
    <service
        android:name="com.music.android.xx.media.MusicService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
<service
    android:name=".service.LocationUpdatesService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" />

<receiver android:name=".service.StopServiceReceiver" />
<receiver android:name=".service.PlayRadioReceiver" />

<service
    android:name=".service.MyFirebaseService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have a problem figuring out what I did wrong or what I missed . Any help will be greatly appreciated..

PS: My app had been in the store for 4days and my App Name have numbers in it like "appX 101.1" (i'm worried that this may be an issue)

Comment: Hey have e you tried this fix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869213/google-actions-home-assistant-custom-app-name-not-recognized-mistaken-for-ano

Comment: i'm not working with assistant custom action, i dont think i need them to play song. I followed the instruction form https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant and the demo app form https://github.com/android/uamp and there is no mention of that

Comment: Just an idea. Perhaps you should first ask Google Assistant to launch your app and see if that works.

Comment: Im facing the same issue. If apps is in foreground and u say "Play X" it works fine but if another app is in foreground for android auto and you say "Play X on Y" it doesnt work. The documentation by google is close to useless.

Comment: @SalahHammouda I am facing the same exact issue. Did you find a solution to this? What did you need to do in order to get this feature working?

Comment: @dell116 apparently there is a fixed list of Apps that can use that feature and coud not find how to apply for it. more details ->  https://github.com/android/uamp/issues/432

Comment: @SalahHammouda The issue you've linked to, I believe, is for a different context. You shouldn't need to enable "voice actions on google" for an Android Auto implementation to recognized intents via voice search.

Comment: @dell116 ya true, i think the one how open the issue is right and u need to be in spécifique list to make think work. the doc not claire in this part. I lost couple months trying to make it work with no luck.